# devextreme-react line chart with data source (reshapeOnPush) 20 elements limit

Tags: javascript, charts, devexpress

I need to realise a line chart for real time energy consumption each 10 seconds.
I am testing devextreme-react with the following sandbox
[Energy chart sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/real-time-updates-devextreme-data-grid-forked-xbwxug?file=/App.js)
This dummy code add 17 occurrences of the data I need in the chart data source

```
{ time: 0, '1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 0 },
{ time: 10, '1': 3, '2': 4, '3': 2, '4': 6 },
{ time: 20, '1': 3, '2': 4, '3': 2, '4': 6 }
etc. etc.
```

When loaded the code in the sandbox adds 17 occurrences and there is a button at the bottom of the chart to simulate the real time feed.

PROBLEM: it is possible to add only until count 19. From count 20 the chart doesn't update.

What am I missing here?

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out that dataSource has pagination activated by default and set to 20.

Fix was simply to deactivate it

```
let chartDataSource = new DataSource({
  store: data,
  paginate: false,
  sort: "time",
  reshapeOnPush: true
});
```